# Draw an image on an adminhtml page

Tags: adminhtml, image, header

I'm trying to draw a bar graph on a page in the backend:

```
$values = array ('Jan' => 10, 'Feb' => 20, 'Mar' => 30);
$img_width=450;
$img_height=300; 
$margins=20;

# ---- Find the size of graph by substracting the size of borders
$graph_width=$img_width - $margins * 2;
$graph_height=$img_height - $margins * 2; 
$img=imagecreate($img_width,$img_height);

$bar_width=20;
$total_bars=count($values);
$gap= ($graph_width- $total_bars * $bar_width ) / ($total_bars +1);

# -------  Define Colors ----------------
$bar_color=imagecolorallocate($img,0,64,128);
$background_color=imagecolorallocate($img,240,240,255);
$border_color=imagecolorallocate($img,200,200,200);
$line_color=imagecolorallocate($img,220,220,220);

# ------ Create the border around the graph ------

imagefilledrectangle($img,1,1,$img_width-2,$img_height-2,$border_color);
imagefilledrectangle($img,$margins,$margins,$img_width-1-$margins,$img_height-1-$margins,$background_color);


# ------- Max value is required to adjust the scale -------
$max_value=max($values);
$ratio= $graph_height/$max_value;

# -------- Create scale and draw horizontal lines  --------
$horizontal_lines=20;
$horizontal_gap=$graph_height/$horizontal_lines;

for($i=1;$i<=$horizontal_lines;$i++){
    $y=$img_height - $margins - $horizontal_gap * $i ;
    imageline($img,$margins,$y,$img_width-$margins,$y,$line_color);
    $v=intval($horizontal_gap * $i /$ratio);
    imagestring($img,0,5,$y-5,$v,$bar_color);

}

# ----------- Draw the bars here ------
for($i=0;$i< $total_bars; $i++){ 
    # ------ Extract key and value pair from the current pointer position
    list($key,$value)=each($values); 
    $x1= $margins + $gap + $i * ($gap+$bar_width) ;
    $x2= $x1 + $bar_width; 
    $y1=$margins +$graph_height- intval($value * $ratio) ;
    $y2=$img_height-$margins;
    imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$y1-10,$value,$bar_color);imagestring($img,0,$x1+3,$img_height-15,$key,$bar_color);        
    imagefilledrectangle($img,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$bar_color);
}
```

Now that I have the $img file set up, I'd like to print it onto the screen (between other information).

If I try this:

```
header("Content-type:image/png");
imagepng($img);
$_REQUEST['asdfad']=234234;
```

It just prints out gibberish, I'm assuming as Magento has already set the page headers

```
�PNG  IHDR�,-8[$PLTE@����������OS� (IDATx���n�(��dqY�4}�8!^bi�����> � ���S����)���t�!���t�� i��)�6c�Z\�D$"��YP���&�����XDP��c�E�%��G4b#,2���k�����?c�y�;�sF��@���HD"]�=-��Ml*�ݪJa+�=��i��K���v�L����g=&גį;l����8�H�'�C,��h����Db���(�K,��x%�g��>.0:�H�;%���ǩ��Zlѕ��Wr٢+���"�V�_s���z~te�uğ������ �#��k�U(���]!"WL{<:�� ~�~;�(�BD"^ 1����צ*9zt��C���JN�"�j��C�����D-��!��ONJND"�,ѡGW�BW�5��i� �x��zsq �'"�_|W�9yTn���2EW���i�J�U���|�v!��w���C��y�c�h�DRĐ%�����>�V]^ɇj˫��5:�H�[!扮$5'Kt%٪Ybɹ]�|��+)%���G�x+�<;I�J.֠��>z��&�Y�d�5:�H�[!�!�������,{W�J�>?�a<���F��͠�܁����o �GWEW�x�ݨr��u��@|�@�4�i�='�Tte7����?���>��Q�����ǔ��h���US���=����=��V]�j2�)&����)��CL}3(��+!~��/��7�d;��_L�q���ʽ��� �č�#:�NTu/�]����h�G�Y�XAlԒ�1>Z�>�r�ޗ����}椒_��鬦_Ǿ�M3�5:�όG썈�:6WG\t<�"���M����E�����2J�=z��ݪ�Ƕ�c�ى�>����>���/�����L�5�����NF�Ab���)��0����}GD2"��1%��6�-�e��c��[����z��V����� ��P�[���z��<� ۊ"~���ڟ�q�ۏ��=��%v����N,@7��7���~ ꘭#JX������*U��=�1N�s�6���i�B�,��Go7Aq͋B;ŕҲ,2�R��E���J�u�u�`�s�?�='Z!CЪ\�B8��+&��Q�)38M��Ghu�>�Ҁ;�qo!g��G�8i��.�h��  \G�$�(�:J#��=��ڿ�9h�/�� ���,AE飏��Qb8�"k�,�i��|��=�P���ot(���-��ˢS(��Ъ >x[hh|k.� �+hj�'��P�6�B(�_薕� �sf�=��Jy���K��H�H�O����NB�mIEND�B`�
```

Anybody got some pointers for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `content-type` header forces the whole adminhtml page to output as PNG image, and since it's not really an image but HTML it turns up all garbled.

If you want to generate an image on the fly you will need a controller in your extension that outputs just that image.

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public fnction graphAction()
    {
        $values = unserialize(base64_decode(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('values')));
        $img_width = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('width');
        $img_height = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('height');
        $margins = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('margin');

        [...]
        the rest of your code
        [...]

        header("Content-type:image/png");
        imagepng($img);
        exit;
    }
}
```

now you can call the image from the Adminhtml like so

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('[module]/index/graph', array('values' => base64_encode(serialize(array('Jan' => 10, 'Feb' => 20, 'Mar' => 30))), 'width' => 500, 'height' => 500, 'margin' => 500));?>"/>
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on, needed to reconfigure a little for myself but exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!